# C# Easy question, how do I loop through an array and display values inline?

Tags: c#

Basically I have this which I know won't work but I it illustrates what I'm trying to do:

MessageBox.Show("Found these: " + keywords[i] + " keywords.");

And I need to see this:

Found these: Item1, Item2 keywords.

There may be 1 keyword there may be 4, how should I do this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [string.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx):

```
MessageBox.Show("Found these: " + string.Join(", ", keywords) 
                + " keywords.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Jon Skeet has a good answer with string.Join. your other option for more complicated formatting would be to use a string builder

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
seperator = "";
foreach(string current in keywords){
 sb.Append(seperator);
 sb.Append(current);
 seperator = ", ";
}

MessageBox.Show("Found these: " + sb.ToString() + " keywords.");
```

Comment: sb.Length -= 2; // Remove the last ", "
Should only happen when a string is in keywords else sb has a negative length and i dont know how it handles it :P